# can I use json-server for heroku

Tags: heroku, json-server

I wanted to use my json-server for my heroku application and can you tell me if this is posible and if it is can you tell me how should I deploy my json-server in my heroku application

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. There's a guide by jesperorb here: https://github.com/jesperorb/json-server-heroku

You can clone that repo and use the package/server.json files or combine them with your current set-up. Might take some fiddling to get it working.

In my experience so far, it is working great to read from, but I have had some problems when POSTing to it. Hope that helps.